# Cheap airport hotel at Sheremetyevo International Airport

Tags: budget, airports, hotels, svo

I need to stay for one night at Sheremetyevo International Airport in Russia and I am looking for a cheap airport hotel (30/40 $ per night), preferrably one that is located within the airport. However, as far as I know, I could not find such hotels. Do I need to find a hotel outside the airport?

I found [Midland Sheremetyevo Hotel](http://www.agoda.com/europe/russia/moscow/midland_sheremetyevo_hotel.html) to be the cheapest, but if anyone who knows better places or suggestions, please let me know.

Only myself (single adult male) will be staying at a hotel.

Comment: What is cheap for you? what's the limit?

Comment: I would say something like $30-40 per night. The cheaper the better.

Comment: You may be interested in the airport's new [V-Express](http://www.eng.v-exp.ru/) hourly capsule hotels.

Comment: Capsule rates start at ~$75 per four-hour block.

Comment: If you can get into town and are ok with a hostel, I stayed at [Chocolate Hostel](http://www.chocohostel.com/) 2 years ago, and it was really comfortable.  People of all ages were there too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the price range you're asking for is impossible.

For close to a decade, Moscow has been [the world's most expensive city for business travel](http://articles.latimes.com/2013/feb/03/business/la-fi-mo-moscow-hotels-travelers-20130201), with hotel rooms costing a ludicrous $414 per night on average according to the linked survey in 2013.  Even the "[V-Express](http://www.eng.v-exp.ru/services/prices2011/)" capsule hotel in SVO, reputedly the temporary home of Edward Snowden, wants 2450 RUR (~US$75) for a mere four hours in a glorified coffin.

There are hostels in central Moscow that can get you a dorm bed for 600 RUR (~US$20), eg. [Napoleon](http://www.napoleonhostel.com/location/), but you'll be sharing the room with half a dozen strangers.  None that I know of are particularly convenient to the airport, and the train ride costs 300 roubles one-way, so you're already up to $40 even for this.  You could theoretically shave off a few kopecks with buses or local trains, but none are convenient or recommended for a first-time visitor.